# How can I disable Editor suggestions in Word 365

Tags: office-365

I'm using the browser version of Word and it seems to have a supposedly helpful "Editor" feature that makes suggestions on improving the language of your text. This goes beyond the usual typo and grammar fixes into more subjective areas like clarity and conciseness.

I hate it and want it to stop making suggestions. It's incredibly annoying because many of them are at best neutral and don't really improve anything and some are just bad and miss the context or purpose of the text. And they are very, very visible because they underline the text directly in the editor view.

I can't figure out how to disable them. There is a settings page under "Review -> Editor -> Editor Settings", but that doesn't seem to do anything. I disabled all options under the "Refinements" section and left spellcheck and grammar fixes on. This doesn't change the behaviour here at all, I still get the suggestions from the refinements section.

The one thing that does work is the "Review -> Editor -> Hide Suggestions" menu option, but that does reset whenever I reload the page. So this isn't a real solution either.

How can I disable these annoying suggestions from the Editor feature permanently?